# Relevanssi show only 1 result

Tags: search

Search works correct, but show only one result Why is that? How can I change it?

I'm using also Dave's WordPress Live Search which show me many results (for example 10), but in search result page I can see only link and little bit of content for 1 page only.

This is my search page:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <h2 class="pagetitle">Search Results For "<?php echo wp_specialchars($s, 1); ?>"</h2>
    <div class="entrytext">
    <?php if (function_exists('relevanssi_the_excerpt')) { relevanssi_the_excerpt(); }; ?>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

How to display more results?

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting "always" for fuzzy matches in the preferences. In the default setting, if search finds only 1 result, fuzzy matching won't get activated.